# How can I use nuget.exe to download protected (private) nuget package from artifactory

Tags: windows, artifactory, nuget-package, jfrog-cli

I'm using nuget.exe 3.4.4 and trying to download a nuget package with is protected (private) (access only allow for certain members of the team). But it gives me `Unable to resolve package_name` error. Public repositories can be download without issue. if I use jfrog.exe to download the same package which is protected, it works without issue.

Is there a restriction in nuget to download protected packages?

**Command**

`A:\Nuget\3.4.4\nuget.exe restore C:\Temp\tmp\project.json -NoCache -NonInteractive -PackagesDirectory A:\Packages -ConfigFile C:\Temp\tmp\nug.config`

**project.json**

`{"dependencies": {"nuget_package_name": "package_version"}, "frameworks": {"45": {}}}`

**nu.config**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<configuration>
<packageSources>
<add key="Artifactory0" value="https://myartifactory_server.com/artifactory/api/nuget/package_name" />
</packageSources>
<packageSourceCredentials>
<Artifactory0>
<add key="Username" value="username" />
<add key="ClearTextPassword" value="password" />
</Artifactory0>
</packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is your Artifactory version ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question, to help if anyone face this issue in future

Artifactory version: 6.8.7
Buy setting `force authentication` flag to 1 for that repository helps to solve this issue